# Delete Special Character Elements, Single Character elements from list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement

I have the below list of strings:

`price_list = ['0W2', '1', '1', '1626.9', '1.4', '0.09', '20/06', '1603.4', '23.5', '1.4', '4:29', '55']`

I need to delete every occurrence of the below from my list:

1. Single digit numbers
2. Special characters such as '/' and ":"
3. Alphabets

My final price_list should be:
`price_list = ['1626.9', '1.4', '0.09', '1603.4', '23.5', '1.4', '55']`

I tried several ways but they only removed the first occurrence.

Comment: what did you try? we cant help you debug your code if you dont show it to us

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can match your values against a regex which looks for an integer of 2 or more digits or a floating point value:

```
import re

price_list = ['0W2', '1', '1', '1626.9', '1.4', '0.09', '20/06', '1603.4', '23.5', '1.4', '4:29', '55']
print([price for price in price_list if re.match(r'(\d{2,}|\d+\.\d+)$', price)])
```

Output:

```
['1626.9', '1.4', '0.09', '1603.4', '23.5', '1.4', '55']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_pricelist = []
price_list = ['0W2', '1', '1', '1626.9', '1.4', '0.09', '20/06', '1603.4', '23.5', '1.4', '4:29', '55']
for price in price_list:
    if len(price) > 1:
        try:
            fl = float(price)
            if isinstance(fl, float):
                new_pricelist.append(fl)
        except:
            pass

print(new_pricelist)
```

Comment: my list is with strings. Apart from floats, I need whole numbers as well as long as they are not single digits

Answer (score 0):

**What About Using Exceptions To Cheat This? See Code Below**

```
newlist = []
for i in price_list:
    try :  
        float(i)
        newlist.append(i)
    except : 
        continue
```

No need to import any module or do anything! Ezy Peezy!

Comment: you can avoid try and except as this is costly operation, plust this don't handle situation when string is integer and of 1 digit

Answer (score 0):

without using regex

```
def func(val):

    dic = { 'int':0,  'decimal':0, 'other':0}
    for i in val:
        if i=='.':
            dic['decimal'] +=1
        elif i.isdigit():
            dic['int']+=1
        else:
            dic['other']+=1
    if dic['decimal']<=1 and dic['int']>1 and dic['other']==0:
        return True
    return False

price_list = ['0W2', '1', '1', '1626.9', '1.4', '0.09', '20/06', '1603.4', '23.5', '1.4', '4:29', '55']

result = list(filter(lambda x:func(x), price_list))

print(result)
```

output

```
['1626.9', '1.4', '0.09', '1603.4', '23.5', '1.4', '55']
```